# How to install packages in R 3.1.3?

Tags: r

I have to use a specific program in R 3.1.3

For that purpose whenever I am trying to install any package it is throwing error

**unable to access index for repository http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.1**

Apparently, it seems the directories in the repos are available from version 3.2 onwards.
Here, I am trying to install shiny package.

Hw to resolve this problem?

Comment: Global options -> Packages->Use secure download method for HTTP. Try unchecking this.

Comment: Did that. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

Per the README at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/ReadMe :

> Packages for R >= 1.7.0 and R < 3.2.0 are available from
> https://cran-archive.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/

So you can try downloading from that site. Note that `install.packages` may not work as it doesn't seem to have the structure of a regular CRAN mirror, but since you're on Windows you should be able to download the zip files and unzip them into your package directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to download anything, I could figure out that any pakage for R >= 1.7.0 and R < 3.2.0 can be installed using following command

```
install.packages("BioPhysConnectoR", dependencies=TRUE, repos ="https://cran-archive.r-project.org/")
```

So, make sure the **repos** is set as

> repos = https://cran-archive.r-project.org/